# Laravel 4 Include package from Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5

I have a problem with packages, because I included Laravel 5 project to Laravel 4 project via composer.
After that, I got the error: *Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests' not found*. 
So, how can I add packages from Laravel 5 to Laraver 4?

I have tried to add "illuminate/auth: 1.1.*":

```
composer.json:
"require": {            
       "illuminate"/auth : "1.1"
}
```

and I got the error like this:

```
 don't install illuminate/auth v1.1.0|don't install laravel/framework 4.1.x-dev
 - Conclusion: remove symfony/http-foundation v2.4.10
 - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v4.1.31
```

Comment: you cannot use packages of Laravel 5 into your laravel 4 projects

Comment: Yes, I can't use it. I have commented that part and now everything works fine.
But, I know that is not correct way. ^^